# Dynamic Nesting of For loops in python

Tags: python, for-loop, recursion, nested-loops, generic-programming

I have a small piece of code that prints all possible ways of filling 'b' balls in 'c' cups considering we can also choose a subset of the balls (like no balls at all):

```
b = 2
c = 3
for i in range(b+1):
    for k in range(b+1):
        for j in range(b+1):
            if i+j+k<=b:
                print(i,k,j)
```

The result is:

```
0 0 0
0 0 1
0 0 2
0 1 0
0 1 1
0 2 0
1 0 0
1 0 1
1 1 0
2 0 0
```

Now, the problem is that this is not a generic code and depending on the number of cups (c), the number of nested For loops needs to be changed. I tried using recursion but was not able to get the desired result.

Can anyone help me with making this code generic such that I just need to enter the value of 'b' and 'c' and get the result without editing the code?

Comment: What does `c` do in your script?

Comment: `c` decides the number of nested loops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using recursive generators

```
def fill(b, c):
    if c == 0:
        yield []
    else:
        for i in range(b+1):
            for sub in fill(b-i, c-1):
                yield [i, *sub]



for o in fill(2, 3):
    print(o)
```

Output

```
[0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 2]
[0, 1, 0]
[0, 1, 1]
[0, 2, 0]
[1, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 1]
[1, 1, 0]
[2, 0, 0]
```

Comment: This method is faster than using the `itertools.product()` function.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need recursion, just `itertools.product`:

```
for t in product(range(b+1), repeat=c):
    if sum(t) <= b:
        print(t)
```

However, recursion would reduce the number of tuples you need to consider by dynamically adjusting each range to account for previous choices.

```
# Untested
def foo(b, c, stop=0):
    for x in range(0, b+1-stop):
        for y in foo(b, c-1, stop + x):
            yield (x, *y)

for t in foo(b, c):
    if sum(t) <= b:
        print(t)
```